# How to improve this hover animation effect with transform: scale and origin?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

Can someone help me to get rid of the choppy "snap" at the end of this hover effect animation that appears in Google Chrome? Or, explain why the "snap" occurs?

I am looking for practical solutions to an effect that makes it feel like the magazine cover is lifted off the shelf a little bit, so up and "out" is the idea I'm going for. If you hover over the cover you'll see that at the very end there is a little choppy snap that is very jarring. I'm trying to get rid of that, and also understand what is going on here. Any help appreciated!

```css
li.newsletter {
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;  
}

.thumb {
     line-height: 1px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}      
.thumb:after{
     content: "";
     display: block;
     height: 16px;
     width: 100%;
     background: #cbcbcb;
     box-shadow: 10px 5px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     width: 100%;
     z-index: +10;
     opacity: 0.99; // z-index stack order hack
}
img {
     transition-duration: 0.2s;
     transition-property: transform;
     transition-timing-function: ease;
     box-shadow: 4px 0px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
a:hover img {
     transform: scale(1.05);
     transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="newsletters">
  <li class="newsletter">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="thumb">
        <img width="100" height="200" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x200/000000/fff.jpg&text=Magazine+Cover" />           </div>
      <div class="title">
      <div class="newsletter-title">Issue No. 15</div>
      <div class="newsletter-date">September 2019</div>
     </div>
    </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: I'm on Safari and not seeing the 'snap' you are describing. Maybe limit your properties to just `transform`, though, that might ease it on the browser regardless.

Comment: You're right @somethinghere, the choppiness doesn't appear in Safari. I'll update the question with that information.

Comment: Also, changing the property to just transform seems to fix most of it. Thanks a ton! If you want to add that as an answer I can accept that.@somethinghere

Comment: I'm not seeing a snap on my Chrome either. But I do recommend setting the initial scale to .95 and the :hover scale to 1.0 instead, it will give a better UX on most browsers scaling-wise.

Comment: Also very clever @MiK Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should consider telling the browsers *exactly* what you want to animate so it doesn't have to set up animations for *all* properties. Simply fo this:

```
transition-property: transform;
```

instead of the initial `transition-property: all;`, as *all* means *all* - even if there is nothing to animate it will compute them. If you can avoid computation you'll get smoother transitions.